# What is the correct table structure to achieve this simple database relationship?

Tags: mysql, database

If you imagine a 'Fantasy Football' database, where you have users' creating leagues, and one user can be apart of many different leagues.

I was going to do something similar to this:

```
create table fantasy_league (
      id int, 
      name varchar(100), 
      password, admin, 
      players_id(array)
 )

create table player_profiles (
      id int, 
      email, 
      display_name varchar(100), 
 leagues_id(array)
)
```

Each league is likely to only have 6 players in it, but I have recently been advised storing an array in one column is not the way to go.

What would be a better alternative?

Comment: Normalize using a table relationship  with following   leagues_id, profile_id, that way let you know all the leagues where is registered a user and also all the user where are registered in a league.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a third table called leagues_players and store id from each table into it.

off course establish the required foreign key relationship/constraints and remove players_id and leagues_id keys from respective tables.

```
create table leagues_players (league_id int, player_id int)
```

Comment: what are: foreign key relationship/constraints?

Comment: please read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396